# How to test two identical process with different scheduling policy and their cpu usage

Tags: linux, cpu, scheduling

what would be the best approach to compare usage of the processor (in  %) for two identical processes with different scheduling policy in for example one-minute time frame.
I'm pretty new to the linux and I'm testing some things... but it's pretty hard for me so I will be glad for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some extra details could have been useful to give you a better answer.

To monitor the CPU activity, you can use the `sar` command like this :

```
sar [interval] [count]
```

So you'll get a short report of CPU usage every `interval` seconds, up to `count` reports.

For example :

```
$ sar 1 3
Linux 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (caramba)    05/14/2019      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

05:18:33 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
05:18:34 PM     all      3.06      0.00      2.55      0.51      0.00     93.88
05:18:35 PM     all      2.07      0.00      2.59      0.00      0.00     95.34
05:18:36 PM     all      1.03      0.00      1.54      0.00      0.00     97.44
Average:        all      2.05      0.00      2.23      0.17      0.00     95.55
```

The manual page (as well as online docs - there are plenty) may put you on track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pidstat [interval][count] -p processID` to monitor specific process. `sysstat` pack provides this and some other tools for monitoring.